# I do not understand why I get this "An Object Reference is Required" error

Tags: c#, exception, object, reference, error-handling

This code reads an array of files and should pass them through to the following class library.

```
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbtnNetIX.Checked == true)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtPath.Text, "*.txt");
            NetEDI.NetIX.Seiko.Seiko.Main(files);

        }
```

should be referenced by the following code.

```
public class Seiko
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<FileDefinition.FileDefinition> fileDefs = new List<FileDefinition.FileDefinition>();
        foreach (string fileEntries in args)
        {

            fileDefs.Add(CreateFileDef(fileEntries));
        }

        foreach (var fileDef in fileDefs)
        {
            XmlCreator CreateXmlDefinition = new XmlCreator(fileDef.FileName + ".xml", fileDef);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line causes the exception? Have you debugged this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `Main` method declaration:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
```

That's an *instance* method - you have to call it on an instance of `Seiko`. But when you try to call it here:

```
NetEDI.NetIX.Seiko.Seiko.Main(files);
```

... you're trying to call it as if it's a static method.

Given the conventions around `Main`, I strongly suspect you want to make it a static method.

(As an aside, you should probably revise the difference between static and instance members, and have another look at the error message: see if you can work out why you didn't figure the problem out yourself, so that next time you run into something similar, you can fix it.)

Comment: Thank you Ive been looking for the answer for 1.5 hours, i'll mark as answer when it allows me (10 min wait)

Answer (score 9):

Main is not **static**, therefore you need an object reference to the `Seiko` class first, in order to call it.

So, here: `NetEDI.NetIX.Seiko.Seiko.Main(files);` - this is a static call to a non static method, hence the error.